# Differences in inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function Person()
{
  this.name="Person"
}

Person.prototype.hi=function(){
  alert("Hello! I'm"+this.name)
}

function Iwanttoinherit(){
  ...
}
```

What is the main difference in OOP inheriting between using

```
Iwanttoinherit.prototype=new Person()
```

and

```
Iwanttoinherit.prototype=Object.create(Person.protoype)
```

Comment: By doing `new Person()` instead of `Object.create(...)`,  any change to the `Person` prototype will also change the `Iwanttoinherit` prototype, but not the other way around. Any properties created/added in the Person constructor will also be a part of the `Iwanttoinherit` prototype. If that's your intention, then that's the method you should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between these two is that `new Person()` causes `Iwanttoinherit` to inherits the `Person` properties, while `Object.create(Person.prototype)` will not.

`Object.create(Person.prototype)`

This creates an object, with an inheritance chain to: `Person.prototype`.

However, `Person.prototype` is just `{}`, in other words: `Object.create({})`, which is the same as `new Object()`, which has no inherited properties

Similarly, `new Person()` creates a `Person` object.  By assigning `Iwanttoinherit.prototype` the `new Person()` value, you're essentially causing the `Iwanttoinherit` object to inherit the `Person` properties.